# Keras: Getting "Found: Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 256, 256, 2), dtype=float32)" error when using the `Input` Layer

Tags: image, keras, neural-network

My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=input_shape))       
model.add(Flatten())

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(120))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.3))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(n_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

My input shape is (256,256,2). I got this error: TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(None, 256, 256, 2), dtype=float32). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Don't use `Input` layer with Sequential API. It already has an input layer. Instead, remove it and set the `input_shape` on `Flatten` layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input doesn't return a layer
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py#L1142

It is a wrapper of InputLayer.
As you are using `Sequential`, just skip it and use the parameter `input_shape`:

```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape = your_input_shape)
```